# Scroll Event is not firing in Angular-6

Tags: html, css, angular6, dom-events, window-scroll

I know this question is asked before, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I am working on the Angular-6 project. I am trying to get Window-Scroll event in one of the components named **SectionComponent**.

Styles of **html** and **body** tag:

```css
html, body {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Below is the **hierarchy of components** which explains how components are managed.

My **AppComponent**:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```js
  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    console.log('scroll');
  }
```

**AppComponent** loads component named **HomeComponent** in the **router-outlet** tag. This **HomeComponent** loads **SectionComponent** by using is selector.

My **HomeComponent:**

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="home-wrapper">
  <div> 
    <!-- Some content more that window height -->
  </div>
  <app-section></app-section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.home-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**home.component.ts:**

```js
  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    console.log('scroll');
  }
```

My **SectionComponent**

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <!-- Some content more than window height -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.section-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 2241px;
}
```

**section.component.ts:**

```js
  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    console.log('scroll');
  }
```

I only want to use Window-Scroll in **SectionComponent**. But none of the components are firing the event. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ScrollDispatcher } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

  constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher) {    
    this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe(x => console.log('I am scrolling'));
  }
```

in tempalte:

```
<div cdkScrollable>
  <div *ngFor="let one of manyToScrollThru">
    {{one}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying on the template with material and nebular components, without success (Angular 11). Is `*ngFor` part necessary, if so what would be its values?

Answer (score -1):

In Your SectionComponent  after the class declaration just use

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event){

var element =  document.getElementsByClassName('section-wrapper')[0];
var rect =   element.getBoundingClientRect();
 // the above code will return the CSS border-boxe associated with the element.
// so on scroll you will have readonly left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, and height properties .
//on behalf of these properties you can manipulate the DOM section-wrapper div.

}
```